# How to use taglib to get information from a audio file

Tags: c#, taglib

At the first when I want to create a file with `Taglib` I get following error.

Error:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'TagLib.File.IFileAbstraction'

```
string fileToOpen=@"D:\music.mp3";
TagLib.File musicinfo = TagLib.File.Create(fileToOpen);
textBox5.Text = musicinfo.Tag.Title;
textBox2.Text = musicinfo.Tag.FirstAlbumArtist;
textBox3.Text = musicinfo.Tag.Album;
```

The path of the file is a string, why does this error appear ?

Comment: Does a File exist at `D:\music.mp3`? Do you get this error during compilation or at runtime?

Comment: Yes The Path is okay and File exist.this error is from while i write the code.Even i write any string i get the same error.

Comment: do you use this lib https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp ?

Comment: Your code works fine here. I use taglib-sharp.dll  v2.0.50727. Is the mp3 file valid?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ,you use correct TagLib.

Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/2.1.0

Github : https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp

> **File** file = **TagLib.File.Create**("string path");

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        File file = TagLib.File.Create(@"C:\Users\MSU-01\Desktop\asd.mp3");
        string title = file.Tag.Title;
        Console.WriteLine(title);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly this, but am seeing compile error "cannot convert from 'string' to 'TagLib.File.IFileAbstraction'". Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I got the latest from nuget and passing in a string for the filepath. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @PHenry Did u try https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp#readwrite-metadata-from-a-video ?

Comment: Thank you OMANSAK for the reply. No, I haven't tried that link..yet. But I was able to get it working, however I needed to do a bit more fiddling with the code to get the stream working, that's the part I found frustrating. The Create now does not seem to use a string (filename) as input and only a stream (and I don't know enough about streams to 'just wing it' unfortunately).Thank you for your time and reply.